# Angularjs Filter with Coffee and Jade

Tags: angularjs, coffeescript, angular-filters

I am using gulp to auto load files and i created a custom filter for angularjs which is throwing me an error as

[image]

**app.coffee file**

```
angular.module 'project', [
  'ui.router'
  'appRouter'
  'appController'
  'appFilter'    
  ]
angular.module 'appRouter', []
angular.module 'appController', []
angular.module 'appFilter', []

# ---
# generated by js2coffee 2.1.0
```

**test.filter.coffee**

```
myfilter = () ->
    return "Alaksandar Jesus Gene"

angular.module('appFilter').filter 'myfilter', myfilter
```

**partial/test/test.jade**

```
h1(class="testClass") Hello {{test.username |myfilter}}
```

How do i clearoff this error.

Comment: It seems to work fine..the issue is because of other code..after removing the filter code..does it work?

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I got it. I missed another arrow mark in the function. I will post it as an answer.

Comment: I was sure about that..Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

The filter function is with two returns as per [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_09). I added one more arrow to the coffee and it worked.

```
myfilter = () ->
    ->
     return "Alaksandar Jesus Gene"

angular.module('appFilter').filter 'myfilter', myfilter
```